# Make Office 365 Excel custom Function Add-in as installer

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins

I have created an Excel custom function add-in by following below link. It's working fine on my local. I need to create a installer out of it so that it can be shared with other users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows

I couldn't find any information so far on how to make a installer out of it. Any help is greatly appreciated.